# UITableView separator issue in iPad 2 vs iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, air, ipad-2

### iPad 2

[image: iPad 2 simulator]

### iPad Air

[image]

As you can see that in iPad 2 and iPad Air both have same OS **iOS 8.1** but the UITableView Separator in iPad 2 display correctly in Both Master and Detail View 
But in iPad 2 you can see that separator in not display correctly looks very dark or its Black color also in Master View Controller Separator also not Display

Does Any have this kind of issue ? Any help will be really helpful,Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your question you refer to "iPad 2" and "iPad 2". Which one is having the problem? I ask because I'm seeing some UITableView issues on an iPad Air 2, but not on the iPad 4.

Comment: The problem is also happening on the "iPad Air" simulator.

Comment: I fixed my problem. It turned out to be a 32/64-bit issue. Our code was returning a 'float' instead of 'CGFloat' in - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath